# How to echo html code file in php?

Tags: php

I want to print exact text files of a file. But, as the file contains HTML code (example:
    `<br/>`,
    `<table>` etc.) the formatting of the page changes. I want to echo exactly what the file contains, 
    `<br/>`, 
    `<table>` etc. printed in the page. How can I do that?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) [Pretty heavy when compared to `htmlspecialchars()`]

```
<?php
echo htmlentities($yourhtmlcontent);
```

Alternatively, you could make use of [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your whole page that way, then you can set the header to

`header('Content-Type:text/plain');`

and then echo our file contents.